# Save Selection As command gives no options--only pdf format savable

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, export, image

I want to insert a Mathematica plot (ListPlot3D) into my question [CopulaQuestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261320/can-the-copuladistributions-be-fitted), but I no longer seem to be given the option of what format to use. Only a pdf seems possible, which I can't then insert (browse or paste) into the indicated stackexchange question.

Comment: I use `Edit >> CopyAs >> Bitmap` then paste directly on the se page using CTRL+v.

Comment: Will try--thanks!

Comment: Worked--thanks!

Comment: @kglr I didn't know that you could just drop in an image to MMA.SE using CTRL+v. That is *very* useful! Thank you for pointing that out.